Axios post request failing from client side
I am sending an axios request from client side to the server side, which is failing.
axios.post(`https://cric360-api.vercel.app/`)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })

This is handled on the server side using this code:
app.get("/", (req, res) => { res.json("Welcome to Cric360-api") })
Now when I enter this URL: https://cric360-api.vercel.app/ in the browser I get the welcome message:
Welcome to Cric360-api
But on the deployed website, I get an axios error. What might be the problem.
EDIT:
On server side this is the CORS code:
app.use(cors(
  {
    origin: ["https://cric360.vercel.app"],
    methods: ["POST", "GET"],
    credentials: true
  }
))

This is the network tab after the post request:
Network tab
SOLVED
On the client I should be doing axios.get instead of axios.post

OK, so it's a CORS error ... does your server allow CORS? Actually, the CORS error is on a login endpoint, the other endpoint is simply a 404 ... maybe because POST is not a GET

So, you allow CORS from cric360-api.vercel.app ... but the server IS cric360-api.vercel.app ... which isn't cross origin (it's same-origin, because it's the same origin) - however, the first issue is still that GET isn't POST (or vice versa)

Please check whether there is some cors issue in the network tab

I am adding the CORS error in the edit, please see if you can help, thanks

THis should no be an answer, it is a comment (at best)
